# What does it mean that the depth of an image is zero?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

In the below code, I am reading an image and displaying the number of channels it has and its depth.

The result is channels:3 and depth:0

As far as I know, the depth should represent the number of bits per channel.

What does it mean that the depth is zero?

**Code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(org.opencv.core.Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    Mat imgSrc = new Mat();
    imgSrc = Highgui.imread(PATH);

    if (imgSrc.empty()) {
        System.out.println("image is empty");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("channels: " + imgSrc.channels());
    System.out.println("depth: " + imgSrc.depth());
}
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can read here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth
The depth field does not contain the actual count of bits. It contains a value of a constant defined in the opencv lib. You would have to check those constants in your version to answer, what a 0 means.

Edit: In my version CvType.CV_8U == 0. So you can expect an unsigned char.

Comment: THis helped me a lot